# Marginal convergence in distribution plus independence imply joint convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$, $Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Does it follow that $(X_n, Y_n) \stackrel{d}{\to} (X,Y)$?

I don't think this is true, but am having trouble coming up with a counter example.

Comment: Try $X_n=Y_n=X$ for every $n$.